# SQL runtime exceptions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I was experimenting something with transactions and I had the following code:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT ROW INTO TABLE1
INSERT ROW INTO TABLE1
INSERT ROW INTO TABLE1
INSERT ROW INTO TABLE1
COMMIT
```

First I put first insert statement to try to insert invalid type of data in the table (char to bool), and runtime exception was thrown and other statements after first one were ignored too.

But when I put first insert statement to try to insert a number in ID column and error was thrown because `IDENTITY_INSERT` is set to OFF, the other statements after that (including COMMIT) were executed and changes were saved to DB.

My question is why the first error stopped everything from executing and the second one didn't? How do I know if runtime error will stop the rest code from execution? I thought that every runtime exception stops execution...

EDIT:

First case (when execution stopped):

```
`Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type bit.`
```

Second case (when execution continued):

```
Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'crmMappingRule' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: I don't recognize the syntax:  `insert row into table1`.

Comment: Its just insert of some data to table. The real statement I wrote is not important for question.

Comment: If you want multiple statements to succeed or fail as a group you should use transactions. That is the whole point of them. Then you wrap those transactions with try/catch

Comment: @Aleksa - you're asking for help about your insert statements and the different runtime errors they cause, but you're not showing us the *actual* insert statements, nor any information about the errors beyond the fact that they're runtime errors. *how* do you imagine that we're going to be able to help you?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever See edit.

Comment: @SeanLange I understand that, I just want to know why some errors stop the execution, and others doesn't. See my edit where I wrote which error stops it and which doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some errors are generated whilst the system is *compiling* the batch. Because these errors prevent the batch from being compiled, the error is returned and no further action takes place.

Other errors are generated whilst the system is *executing* the compiled batch. These errors may terminate the execution of an individual statement but will allow execution to proceed onto the next statement<sup>1</sup>.

Some errors may be generated at either compile time or execution time, so there aren't just two lists of "Errors that will happen during compilation" and "Errors that will happen during compilation". For instance, your first error concerning converting a `varchar` to `bit`. In this instance, it obviously happened at compile time, and so was probably a `varchar` literal within your query. But, if the `varchar` value had been coming from another table, it would have been an execution time error.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Some* errors will abort the batch. It's not clearly documented anywhere which ones will, and for some it depends on the XACT_ABORT setting that's in force. I guess it's not as clear cut as I remembered.